# How to attach proxy automatic configuration script information to HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

My computer's proxy setting is using automatic configuration script and its address is like:http://gazproxy.xxxxxx.com:81/proxy.pac, I can visit websites normally, but when I tried to use GetResponse() method of a HttpWebRequest instance as follow:

```
        public static string GetContent(string url)
    {
        string data = string.Empty;
        Uri uri=new Uri(url);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Referer = uri.Host;
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.29 Safari/537.36";
        request.Method = "GET";

        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();
        proxy.Address = new Uri("http://gazproxy.xxxxxx.com:81/proxy.pac");             
        request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        request.Proxy = proxy;                        


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader readStream = null;
            if (response.CharacterSet == null)
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream);
            else
                readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));
            data = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            response.Close();
            readStream.Close();
        }

        return data;
    }
```

it will throw a exception"The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.",what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with this line:

```
proxy.Address = new Uri("http://gazproxy.xxxxxx.com:81/proxy.pac");
```

The URI you wrote actually refers to an automatic configuration script, and not to a proxy server. You will need to open and inspect that configuration script to know what is the actual proxy server. For that purpose, copy paste that URL on a browser address bar, and either view / download or save a copy of the same.

The WebProxy object does not have the intelligence to go read some configuration script and identify the real proxy server.

### From MSDN ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webproxy.address%28v=vs.90%29.aspx )

*WebProxy.Address Property*

The Address property contains the address of the **proxy server**. When automatic proxy detection is not enabled, and no automatic configuration script is specified, the Address property and BypassList determine the proxy used for a request.